# How to create tutorial videos?

Tags: software-recommendation, tutorial

I'd like to know how to create a video tutorial like:

Is there any 'easy to use software' to achieve such effects? I've tried [AVS4YOU](http://www.avs4you.com/) and other beginner animation software packages, but I don't get it.

I really appreciate any help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simple video animation for teaching purpose](http://video.stackexchange.com/questions/15331/simple-video-animation-for-teaching-purpose)

Comment: This is not a duplicate question because I'm looking for an easy to use software (for beginners or layman) the link which you referred is a good software but profession

Comment: Welcome Sam :) What if there is no _easy to use software_ for what do you want to achieve? The referenced answer could help you anyway, because it contains the following link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_2D_animation_software Please try to be specific as you can, so no misunderstandings can arise. Anyway, enjoy video.se!

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I don't think those videos look very good. I certainly wouldn't take their message seriously given their poor quality.

But that point aside, many people use either [Apple Motion](http://www.apple.com/final-cut-pro/motion/) or [Adobe After Effects](http://www.adobe.com/products/aftereffects.html?promoid=KFMVM) to create motion graphics. Motion offers "behaviors" that make moving objects around a little easier if you aren't familiar with keyframing.

Comment: Thanks, I'm checking almost  all the software's and will update here and you as well  very soon with the current update.